# Replacing &quot; with " using common methods does not work in a JavaScript Azure Function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, telligent

## Goal

Transform HTML extracted from Telligent (an extranet platform) to plain text and send to Slack

## Setup

A Telligent webhook is triggered when an event occurs. An Azure Logic App receives the event JSON. The JSON value is in HTML. A JavaScript Azure Function inside the Azure Logic App pipeline transforms the JSON value to plain text. The final step in the pipeline posts the plain text in Slack.

## Example of incoming code to the Azure Function

```
"body": "<p>&quot; &#39;</p><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>"
```

## Transformation method

This is the basic code in the Azure Function. I have left out parts that seem irrelevant to this question but can provide the entire script if that is necessary.

```
module.exports = function (context, data) {
   var html = data.body;

// Change HTML to plain text
   var text = JSON.stringify(html.body);
   var noHtml = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
   var noHtmlEncodeSingleQuote = noHtml.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
   var noHtmlEncodeDoubleQuote = noHtmlEncodeSingleQuote.replace(/&quot;/g, "REPLACEMENT");

// Compile body for Slack
   var readyString = "Slack text: " + noHtmlEncodeDoubleQuote;

// Response of the function to be used later
   context.res = {
     body: readyString
   };

   context.done();
};
```

## Results

The single quote is replaced successfully and resolves accurately when posted in Slack.

The following replacement methods for the double quote throw a `Status: 500 Internal Server Error` within the Azure Function.

### Unsuccessful replacement methods

```
"\""
'"'
&quot;
"'"'"
"["]"
"(")"
```

Putting these replacement methods in their own `var` also throws the same error. E.g.:

```
var replace = "\""
...
var noHtmlEncodeDoubleQuote = noHtmlEncodeSingleQuote.replace(/&quot;/g, replace);
```

The code appears to be correct because when I replace `&quot;` with something like `abc`, the replacement is successful.

### Thank you

Please forgive my JavaScript as I am not a programmer and am seeking to streamline a process for my job. However I am grateful for any advice both about the code or my entire approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you don't want to try to parse HTML with regular expressions or string replacement.  There are just too many things that can go wrong.  [See this now famous StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/634824)  (It was even [made into a T-Shirt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition).)

Instead, you should use a technique that is purposefully built for this purpose.  If you were in a web browser, you could use the techniques described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/634824).  But in Azure Functions, your JavaScript doesn't run in a browser, it runs in a Node JS environment.  Therefore, you need will need to use a library such as [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/) or [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) (and others).

Here is an example using Cheerio:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var text = cheerio.load(html.body).text();
```

Also, regarding this part:

> ... as I am not a programmer ...

Yes you are.  You are clearly programming right now.  Anyone who writes code is a programmer.  There is no club or secret handshake.  We all start out exactly like this.  Good job asking questions, and good luck on your journey!